# If value of column is equal to a certain value then change the value of the next column (python)

Tags: python, mapping

after using pycountry_convert to map countries to continents I have a lot of "Unknown" values in my continent column. One of the cases is when country == 'UK'

I want to replace all the "Unknown" values where the column country == 'UK' with 'Europe' but nothing seems to work. So far I've tried map and the following code but then all my continent values turn into 'EU'

```
for i in locations['location1']:
        if i == 'UK':
            locations['continent'] = 'EU'
```

What I have:

```
     location1   continent
0    USA         NA
1    Peru        SA
2    UK          Unknown
3    NaN         Unknown
```

What I want:

```
     location1   continent
0    USA         NA
1    Peru        SA
2    UK          EU
3    NaN         Unknown
```

Comment: Is there code missing? What is `i`? What is `locations`?

Comment: locations is just the name of an imported data frame and I only defined i for the "for"

Comment: thanks for updating the post ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data-structure is a `pandas` dataframe, I made a stand-alone example that should do the job:

```
import pandas

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["col1"] == 2:
        row["col2"] = 10
        
print(df)
```

I iterate through the rows and change the second column value based on the condition on the first.

**EDIT:**
I just learned that it can be done much more efficiently in pandas:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] == 2, 'col2'] = 10
```

So in your case:

```
df.loc[df['location1'] == 'UK', 'continent'] = 'EU'
```